# XP from Challenges

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

If I complete a challenge, do I get the XP for it or do I need to complete the other tiers for it too to get the XP?

For example, the first challenge in Game Modes > TDM, is veteran. Do I get the XP if I complete the challenge for just 1 of the 3 tiers or do I need to complete all 3 tiers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody has answered this, you get XP for every tier that you accomplish. So if you complete veteran 1 you get XP, once you complete veteran 2 you get more xp, etc. So to answer your question yes you get XP for every tier that you complete in the challenges. It gets incrementally more when you go up in tiers.